# TypeError: Cannot read property 'userData' of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, forms-authentication, angular-services

I am trying to check if authService.userData as user for verifying email for authentication, it just returns the property is undefined and I don't understand why. Maybe my knowledge in angular is lacking but I can't find an explanation of this anywhere. This is my auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../service/user";
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  userData: any; // Save logged in user data

  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    public router: Router,  
    public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
  ) {    
    /* Saving user data in localstorage when 
    logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    })
  }

  // Sign in with email/password
  SignIn(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }

  // Sign up with email/password
  SignUp(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign 
        up and returns promise */
        this.SendVerificationMail();
        this.SetUserData(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }

  // Send email verfificaiton when new user sign up
  SendVerificationMail() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['verify-email']);
    })
  }

  // Reset Forggot password
  ForgotPassword(passwordResetEmail) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(passwordResetEmail)
    .then(() => {
      window.alert('Password reset email sent, check your inbox.');
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }

  // Returns true when user is looged in and email is verified
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
  }

  // Sign in with Google
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  // Auth logic to run auth providers
  AuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
       this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        })
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }

  /* Setting up user data when sign in with username/password, 
  sign up with username/password and sign in with social auth  
  provider in Firestore database using AngularFirestore + AngularFirestoreDocument service */
  SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified
    }
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    })
  }

  // Sign out 
  SignOut() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
    })
  }

}
```

This is the component where i am getting error.

verify-email.component.html

```
<div class="displayTable">
    <div class="displayTableCell">

      <div class="authBlock">
        <h3>Thank You for Registering</h3>

        <div class="formGroup" *ngIf="authService.userData as user">
          <p class="text-center">We have sent a confirmation email to <strong>{{user.email}}</strong>.</p>
          <p class="text-center">Please check your email and click on the link to verfiy your email address.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Calling SendVerificationMail() method using authService Api -->
        <div class="formGroup">
          <button type="button" class="btn btnPrimary" (click)="authService.SendVerificationMail()">
            <i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i>
            Resend Verification Email
          </button>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="redirectToLogin">
        <span>Go back to?<span class="redirect" routerLink="/sign-in"> Sign in</span></span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the error i am getting

[image]

verify-email.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../service/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-verify-email',
  templateUrl: './verify-email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./verify-email.component.css']
})
export class VerifyEmailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( public authservice: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: please add the content of your verify-email.component.ts

Comment: Obviously `authService` is not defined. Can you please check if it is properly initialized/injected... For example, in constructor `constructor(public authService: AuthService)`...

Comment: @GérômeGrignon I have added the verify-email.component.ts now

Answer (score 1):

In your `VerifyEmailComponent.html:7` you can add a safe navigation operator like this:
`*ngIf="authService?.userData as user"`. It will either solve the problem or point you closer to the origin.

Comment: it's called a safe operator in such case : an elvis operator evaluates two operands.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo mistake on `authService`:

component.ts file (authservice) :

```
constructor( public authservice: AuthService) { }
```

component.html file (auth**S**ervice):

````
<div class="formGroup" *ngIf="authService.userData as user">
```service* is undefined in your component.ts (but *auth**S**ervice* is), you can't
````